# Android ant build: how to run android upload and not update build.xml, proguard.cfg

Tags: android

I am running the standard ant script build.xml which gets created when you run the `android create project` command. In order to verify my `local.properties` is set correctly, I added a task at the beginning of the `build.xml` script to run the command:

```
android update project -p .
```

I now get the following message each time I run the ant script, which clobbers my `build.xml` file and creates a `proguard.cfg` file!

> File build.xml is too old and needs to be updated

So, I moved the ant script to a different file that won't get clobbered.

Is there a way to run the command `android update project -p .` that doesn't clobber `build.xml` and create `proguard.cfg`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug.  I have registered a new bug with Google here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17825

If anyone else thinks it's a bug, then please star it and perhaps contribute your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for this. Add the following code in build.xml.

```
<!-- The following will prevent for 'android' tool to overwrite this file.

     (until sdk r12)
     classname="com.android.ant.SetupTask"

     (since sdk r13 FIXME)
     version-tag:custom
-->
```

With the piece of comment, **'android update project'** will not complaint or overwrite the build.xml.
As of now, there might be chance for changes in r13.

- sdk r13 not yet released
- it's based on aosp/master branch

updateProject() in package *com.android.sdklib.internal.project.ProjectCreator* determine to update the build.xml or not.
(The code from sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/internal/project/ProjectCreator.java)

Answer (score 0):

The build.xml generated by android has the following comment:

---

```
     ****** IMPORTANT ******
     ***********************
     In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
     in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
```

so, it looks like Atham is right.